# Books on in-memory databases

Tags: database, nosql, in-memory-database

I am writing a paper on In-memory databases and as an abstract I would like to write about classification of databases and a as a type of db there are In-memory databases.
But I can't find an appropriate book or published article on that topic to make a reference from. 
I would be greatful if I find some advices here, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a few published articles you can reference (from oldest to newest):
[In-Memory Database Systems](https://www.linuxjournal.com/article/6133)

[In-Memory vs. On-Disk Database Systems](https://www.ciol.com/in-memory-vs-on-disk-database-systems/)

[Keeping it All in Memory](https://www.eejournal.com/article/20110706-inmemory/)

[101: An Introduction to In-Memory Database Systems](https://web.archive.org/web/20130719065616/http://www.low-latency.com/article/101-introduction-memory-database-systems)

[In-memory data grids see 2013 as a big year](https://sdtimes.com/big-data/in-memory-data-grids-see-2013-as-a-big-year/)

[Interview: Jeff Chang And Steve Graves Cover In-Memory Databases](https://www.electronicdesign.com/technologies/dev-tools/article/21799098/interview-jeff-chang-and-steve-graves-cover-inmemory-databases)

[8 Fundamentals You Need to Know About Data Persistence and In-Memory Computing](https://it.toolbox.com/blogs/erpdesk/8-fundamentals-you-need-to-know-about-data-persistence-and-in-memory-computing-101314)

[In-Memory Database Technology for Telecom. Interview with Manjul Maharishi](http://www.odbms.org/blog/2015/07/in-memory-database-technology-for-telecom-interview-with-manjul-maharishi/)
[Memory muscle](https://www.fintechfutures.com/2016/02/memory-muscle/)

There are also a couple of whitepapers on our (McObject's) website that might be useful (no registration needed):

[In-Memory Database Systems: Myths and Facts](https://www.mcobject.com/download/in-memory-database-systems-myths-and-facts/)

[Will The Real IMDS Please Stand Up?](https://www.mcobject.com/download/will-the-real-imds-please-stand-up-2/)